# jest babel plugins conflict

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Using Jest + babel.

Babel Config

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }], "@babel/preset-typescript"],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }]
    ]
};
```

Docs state that decorator plugin should be befor the class properties, which I'm doing.
But I'm still getting this error

```
"Unexpected Token"
public showReorderTooltip = false; 
       ^
```

Jest Config

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.[t|j]s?$": "babel-jest",
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
    },
    // transformIgnorePattclaerns: [],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "^common/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/common/$1",
        "^price/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/price/$1",
        "^eligibility/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/eligibility/$1"
    }
};
```

I added the class properties plugin due to an error I was having where it wouldn't transpile the public static variables on a class. Now it does that. But then it didn't like the decorator I had at the top. Ok, seems to be a plugin. That works, but now it doesn't like class properties again? Or is there yet *another* plugin to handle "normal" class properties?

The entire project setup is

- vue-property-decorator //where the decorators are coming from
- typescript
- vue
- vuetify
- some other minor libraries
- vue-cli //not using webpack directly though I imagine the vue-cli is using it

package.json

```
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",        

        "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",            
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.136",
        "@types/qs": "6.5.3",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.1.2",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.32",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
        "css-loader": "2.1.1",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "sass": "^1.23.7",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
        "tslint": "5.16.0",
        "typescript": "3.4.5",
        "vee-validate": "2.2.7",
        "vue": "2.6.10",            
        "vue-class-component": "7.2.2",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.0",
        "vue-router": "3.0.6",        
        "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "1.5.4",
        "vuetify": "^2.2.8",
        "vuex": "3.1.1",
        "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0",
        "vuex-typescript": "3.0.2"
```

Since other files are working, I'm posting a working file and the file causing issues to see if there's some obvious setup issue.

Working Test

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop, Inject, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import moment from "moment";
import * as _ from "lodash";


export const DATE_FORMAT = "MM-DD-YYYY";
export const DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD = "YYYY-MM-DD";


@Component({
})
export default class PEMDatePicker extends Vue {

    @Prop()
    label: string;

    @Prop()
    value: string;

    @Prop()
    rules: Array<Function>; //https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#creating-rules

    public componentsLabel = "";
    public componentsDate = "";
    public showPicker = false;
    public componentsDateInput: string = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    public mounted() {

        this.componentsLabel = this.label ? this.label : "Date";
        this.setDate(this.value);

        this.$emit('input', this.value);

    }

    @Watch("value")
    public syncModel() {
        if (this.componentsDate != this.value) {

            this.setDate(this.value);
        }

        this.componentsDateInput = this.getDate;

    }

    @Watch("componentsDate")
    public syncDates() {
        this.componentsDateInput = this.getDate;
        this.$emit('input', this.componentsDate);
    }

    get getDate() {
        return this.componentsDate ? moment(this.componentsDate, DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD).format("MM/DD/YYYY") : "";
    }

    public closePicker() {
        this.showPicker = false;
        //@ts-ignore
        this.$refs.input.focus();
    }

    public handleEnterKey(event) {

        this.setDate(event.target.value);
        this.showPicker = false;
    }

    setDate(dateIn) {
        this.componentsDate = dateIn && moment(dateIn).isValid() ? moment(dateIn).format(DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD) : null;
    }
}
```

Not Working Test

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Prop, Component, Watch, Inject } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import moment from 'moment';
import ItemService from 'common/items/ItemService';


@Component({
    components: {
        VendorLink: require("price/components/vendor/vendorLink/VendorLink.vue").default,
    }
})
export default class CatalogNumberHistory extends Vue {



    @Prop({ required: true })
    uin: number;

    @Inject("cglItemService")
    itemService: ItemService;

    public showReorderTooltip = false;
    public reorderContainerSize = "";
    public moment = moment;

    public itemCatalogHistory: CatalogHistory[] = [];
    loading: boolean = false;

    mounted() {

        this.getCatalogHistory();
    }

    public async getCatalogHistory() {
        try {

            this.loading = true;
            let result = await this.itemService.getv2ItemByUIN(this.uin);
            this.loading = false;

            if (result.success) {
                this.itemCatalogHistory = result.data.expiredCatalogNumbers;
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            this.$snotify.error(error.message);
        }
    }
}

export interface CatalogHistory {
    expireDate: string;
    catalogNumber: number;
}
```

Comment: I think we need versions of packages, particularly babel and plugins. Even then it may be tough to debug. Your best bet may sadly be to fork the whole repo, delete almost everything except what you need to reproduce the bug, and share the github link. It might just be better to post an issue in the jest github issue tracker as well (they'll want the fork to play with)

Comment: Possibly. I've added some other files to the testing suite that also have class properties, and they work. So it's something weird about this specific file.

Comment: In that case, might as well share the file that’s working and the file that’s not working so we can compare.

Comment: how can this even work "public componentsDateInput: string = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");"

Comment: @StefanAvramovic I'm not sure where your confusion is at. That's just a class property with a type of string that initializes to today's date formatted as MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: It loocks like publik key:  "value" = "something" i am not getting the logic